# Outputting information from MySQL to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, select

There is a code in SQL:

```
SELECT  users.login AS 'Все заказы' , items.title AS ' '  FROM `orders`
JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id 
JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id
```

The code itself in IntelliJ IDEA

```
public  void vivod(String table) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT  users.login AS `Все заказы` , items.title'  FROM `orders`" +
                 "JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id" +
                 "JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id";

        Statement statement = getDbConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery( sql );
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println( res.getString( "orders" ) );


        }

    }
```

In SQL, it outputs correctly, but when inserted into IntelliJ IDEA, it gives an error

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'items ON orders.item_id = items.id' at line 1

The end result should be like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78tvC.png)

What is causing the error?

Comment: change **"JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id" +** to **"JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id " +** . there is no space between order_user_id and JOIN in the next line

Comment: @BerndBuffen
writes: Cannot invoke "String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)" because the return value of "com.mysql.cj.result.Field.getName()" is null

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove redundant quotes from sql statement
So the code in IDEA will look like

`String sql = "SELECT  users.login AS 'Все заказы' , items.title  FROM orders" + "JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id" + "JOIN items ON orders.item_id  = items.id";`

Hope it will work